# How to setup Routes using React Router in my ReactJS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have some problem with react-router. It doesn't go to `Edit` page when I click on `id`. The `id` is in URL, but it doesn't do anything.

```
const Main = (props) => {
    const { pathname } = props.location;
    
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <Header />
                    {pathname === "/create" ? <Create /> : null}
                    {pathname === '/edit/:id' ? <Edit /> : null}
                    {pathname === "/" ? <Home /> : null}

                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default withRouter(Main);
```

**app.js:**

```
require('./components/Index');

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

import Index from "./components/Index";
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
const App =() =>{

}

if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Router> <Index />  <ToastContainer /></Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./CRUD/Main";
import Create from "./CRUD/Create";
import Edit from "./CRUD/Edit";
import Home from "./CRUD/Home";

const Index = (props) => {
    return (
        <Main>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/Create" component={Create} />
                    <Route path='/edit/:id' component={Edit} />
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                </Switch>
        </Main>
    );
};

export default Index;
```

I think `main.js` have some problems with `pathname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) like you are doing in `Main` when using [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/). [`Switch`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) will automatically render the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that will match the location.

Hence, you need to remove `Main` from your router component i.e. `Index` so that it looks like as shown below:

```
const Index = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar /> {/* NavBar is optional, I just added for example */}
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/create" component={Create} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

**NavBar:** (`Link`s; just for example)

```
function NavBar() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/create">Go to create</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/edit/123">Go to edit with id = 123</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Go to home</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Now, when you click on the above links, it will automatically take you to the related component (as declared in routes i.e. `Index`). (*no manually condition checking*)

And example, to retrieve the [URL param](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params) i.e. `id` in `Edit` component using [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook:

```
function Edit() {
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>(); // Remove <{ id: string }> if not using TypeScript
  return <h2>Edit, {id}</h2>;
}
```

Comment: in function navbar when id = 123 it shows edit page . i want                                                <Link to="/edit/123">Go to edit with id = 123</Link>  get id

Comment: You want ID to be dynamic in that Link instead of hardcoding as 123 ?